# how to change output format of a PHP JSON file

Tags: php, android, json

I am working in my Android app with JSON files. I am following a tutorial and now I have detected a problem with the output format of the PHP JSON file I am using.

This is the output format I need for my app:

```
   {
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c202",
                "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
                "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c203",
                "name": "John Wayne",
                "email": "john_wayne@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c204",
                "name": "Angelina Jolie",
                "email": "angelina_jolie@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c205",
                "name": "Dido",
                "email": "dido@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c206",
                "name": "Adele",
                "email": "adele@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c207",
                "name": "Hugh Jackman",
                "email": "hugh_jackman@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c208",
                "name": "Will Smith",
                "email": "will_smith@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c209",
                "name": "Clint Eastwood",
                "email": "clint_eastwood@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c2010",
                "name": "Barack Obama",
                "email": "barack_obama@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c2011",
                "name": "Kate Winslet",
                "email": "kate_winslet@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c2012",
                "name": "Eminem",
                "email": "eminem@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the output format I a getting with my PHP file:

```
[{"idCategoria":"21","nombreCategoria":"Deporte"},{"idCategoria":"22","nombreCategoria":"Hosteler\u00eda y restauraci\u00f3n"},{"idCategoria":"23","nombreCategoria":"Moda y complementos"},{"idCategoria":"24","nombreCategoria":"Ocio y eventos"},{"idCategoria":"28","nombreCategoria":"Otros servicios"},{"idCategoria":"25","nombreCategoria":"Salud y belleza"},{"idCategoria":"26","nombreCategoria":"Servicios profesionales"},{"idCategoria":"27","nombreCategoria":"Tiendas y comercio"}]
```

Please, don't take into account the content and objects names, it is the JSON format what I need to change:

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$host= 'localhost';
$db = 'xxxx';
$uid = 'xxx';
$pwd = 'xxx';
$link = mysql_connect($host,$uid,$pwd) or die("No se puede conectar ");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("No se puede seleccionar la bbdd");
$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbcategorias ORDER BY nombreCategoria asc");
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
$arr[] = $obj;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

What should I change inside my PHP code to obtain the same format as in the first case I showed you above in this question?

Comment: What exactly do you need? What do you mean by "format"? Do you mean you want the whitespace added (new lines and tabs) or is it the structure of the data? You should post an example of the "format" you want from your sample data, not some other random data. Even if that means you have to format it by hand at first. Also, just so you know, whitespace in json is ignored.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, another  user has helped me, thank you in any case...

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, thank you again for your comment, but I don't understand why did you voted my question as unclear if it has two answers from other users.

Comment: It wasn't clear what the question was. That was why I was asking for more clarification. People will still try to answer to the best of their ability, but since it is not clear what you are asking, they are just guesses.

Comment: OK @JonathanKuhn, may be it is a language problem. Thank you.

Comment: The word "format" is kind of ambiguous. It could mean you want the code to have tabs and newlines, or it could mean the structure of your array that you are passing to json_encode. Or it could mean both. It also makes it more confusing when you give an example of what you want the "format" to be and it doesn't match the structure of the data you have. You did say "don't take into account the content and objects names", but by that line, the `Categorias` part in the answer was not needed as that is part of the content.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, it is OK, please don't waste more time with my question. It is now clear to me. The only thing I don't like about the whole thing is that while there are people putting my answer on hold without giving any explanation or reason for it  or asking me for additional information, there is one user who answers to my question. From these five users you are the only one who asks me to clarify my question, and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is that the php output is throwing an a array of objects so it has:

```
[{
    "idCategoria":"21","nombreCategoria":"Deporte"
},{
    "idCategoria":"22","nombreCategoria":"Hosteler\u00eda y restauraci\u00f3n"
}]
```

I guess you should be outputting something like:

```
{
    "Categorias": [{
            "idCategoria":"21","nombreCategoria":"Deporte"
        }, {
            "idCategoria":"22","nombreCategoria":"Hosteler\u00eda y restauraci\u00f3n"
        }]
}
```

So inside of "Categorias" you have an array of all the categories like sports and hotels.. ;)

In PHP I thing should try:

```
$json = array("Categorias" => $arr);
echo json_encode($json);
```

I haven't tried this.. but the important thing is the idea..

Here you can see the output:

http://ideone.com/iO9n4k

Comment: This is fine, it works like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

json_encode has a FLAG called `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`, so you can use

```
echo json_encode($arr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

If that's what you mean by "format".

Comment: Thank you, I already have a working answer. Thank you for your time and effort.